# Can't install MongoDB for PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7.2

I'm trying to use `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mongodb` on an ubuntu 16.04 droplet running nginx and PHP 7.2, and every time I try to run this line I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
php7.0-fpm
```

..and plenty more above that although I'm not sure why it's still trying to use PHP 7.0 here.

I've found walkthroughs for installing mongo and then upgrading PHP from 7.0 to 7.2, but how can I install Mongo after the 7.2 upgrade?

Comment: Did you have PHP7.0 installed prior to your installing PHP 7.2? How did you upgrade PHP7.0 to 7.2? When you did that, did you also upgrade all dependencies of PHP7.0? There a tutorial that shows how to upgrade all 7.0 dependencies to 7.2: https://medium.com/andrewmmc-io/upgrade-php-version-to-7-2-from-7-0-c005a0926642. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, upgraded directly from 7.0 to 7.2.
I've just checked which modules are installed and compiled using the guide you referred to, and all dependancies are upgraded to 7.2 already.

Comment: It sounds like you have some residual files left over from the upgrade. Have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: Have you tried `dpkg — get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep php7.0` to see if there are left-over dependencies? If so, upgrade or purge them. Else, check if `php -v` outputs the correct php-fpm version (7.2). Make sure there´s no php-fpm 7.0 on your machine (`apt-get purge php7.0-fpm`), or re-configure dpkg in case there really is nothing left. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does running `apt-get autoremove`, as @citysurrounded suggested, help? Try also running 'apt-get update`, `apt-get -f install` and `dpkg --configure -a`. You may want to comment out all lines in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].postinst`, then try apt-get again.